# JavaScript / HTML using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to get a value from an HTML input.

In the Firefox console I can see that the output of the command:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("InputSwapFirst"));
```

is:

```
<input id="InputSwapFirst" class="inputSwap" type="text">
Quicksort.js:60:13
```

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Quicksort.js:60:13 is a line number in a file... If you want to access the value of an input you have to use .value and make sure the id is correct and unique.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `.value` to the end - to retrieve the input field's value:

`console.log(document.getElementById("InputSwapFirst").value);`